# Android WIFI connected without internet

Tags: wi-fi

I have Galaxy s20 with android 11. I am connecting at work to WIFI which require to login using a browser. After that unless admin do not change the password mobile connecting automatically without any problems.

After several hours(2-3 usually) of smooth working connection I start having a problem - like connected without internet, or it become very very slow that browser will not load any page.

Here is what I did so far

1. checked other users and no one has this problem which means
   router and internet is OK.
2. switch off and on WIFI several times no succuseed.
3. turned off/on the the mobile no succeed
4. Forget WIFI which worked first time only- then forget stopped working
   and it keep connecting again without asking for password.
5. I have search on the internet and tried all possible solution nothing
   works.
   Any one have idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: I would first disable privacy setting for that WiFi (use real MAC address). Second disable Private DNS for all networks as this could prevent you from reaching the captive portal.

Answer (score 0):

you must visit the url of captive portal manually by typing in address bar of your browser